# Print first 5 rows of large csv file (not using pandas)

Tags: python, csv

Im attempting to simplify a python code that will print the first five rows (plus header) of a large csv file in a more condensed output if possible.  I would prefer to use pandas, however in this case I would like to just to just use the import cv and import os (Mac user).

Code as follows:

```
import csv
 
filename = "/Users/xx/Desktop/xx.csv"
 
fields = []
rows = []
 
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     
    fields = next(csvreader)
 
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
 
    print("Total no. of rows:%d"%(csvreader.line_num))
 
print('Field names are:' + ', '.join(field for field in fields))

print('\nFirst 5 rows are:\n')
for row in rows[:5]:
    for col in row:
        print("%10s"%col,end=" "),
    print('\n')
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? The only suggestion I have is to break out of the `for row in csvreader:` loop after you've read 5 rows. You don't have to read the whole file if you only want the first 5 rows.

Comment: `for rownum, row in enumerate(csvreader): if rownum == 5: break`

Comment: Hey there MattDMo, I don't think anything is wrong with the code, I was trying to simplify it, if possible :-)